# Systemd init message appears when booting OpenRC

Tags: systemd, x86, openrc

I´m using [Parabola](https://www.parabola.nu/) (Arch based) with OpenRC. It had originally Systemd, but then I moved to OpenRC. I don´t know why but when I turn on my PC, it appears the message error "Failed to find cpu0 device node" and "starting version 231" from Systemd, and then it displays "OpenRC [version] is starting up Parabola (i386)"

It does not harm my system, and does not matter, but I would like to know why this happens and if it could be removed

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This message is not coming from systemd. I don't believe this question is systemd related.

Comment: Is it comming from (systemd-)udevd instead of systemd? Can't tell until you post the whole relevant log entry.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to troubleshooting Linux but it does sound like a udev issue. Systemd is a device and service manager. Using the udev code. OpenRC is just the service manager. From the way the error sounds it's probably coming from udev

Answer (score 0):

I see this message when I boot up an i686 (32 bit) ISO, it is a debug message by the kernel AFAIK.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1254210

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an initramfs created before you switched to OpenRC, the message displayed may be a leftover from that.